# Displaying messages on chat screen that I sent or was sent to me

Tags: flutter, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I am using ListView.builder to show my list of messages that I sent and was sent to me.

My ListView.builder code

```
ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _chats.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    MessageModel message = _chats[index];
            
                    return Builder(builder: (_) {
                      if (message.type == 'text') {
                        return Align(
                          alignment: message.sendby ==
                                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email
                              ? Alignment.centerRight
                              : Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints:
                                const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Card(
                                  elevation: 1,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                                  color:
                                      const Color.fromRGBO(2, 132, 213, 1),
                                  child: Stack(children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 15,
                                        right: 15,
                                        top: 10,
                                        bottom: 10,
                                      ),
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            message.message.toString(),
                                            textAlign: message.sendby ==
                                                    FirebaseAuth.instance
                                                        .currentUser!.email
                                                ? TextAlign.right
                                                : TextAlign.left,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                                ),
```

The issue is when I sent a message, it doesn't immediately show the messages that I sent. Same goes for the person who sent me the message. I would need to get out of the chat screen and click the group chat again to see the recent message. How do I show the messages without the need to click the back button?

My DatabaseService.dart

```
    class DatabaseService {
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  static Future<List<MessageModel>> getChats() async {
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    DatabaseReference chatting = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('chats');
    chatting.keepSynced(true);

    final database =
        await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('chats').once();

    List<MessageModel> chats = [];
    Iterable<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshot = database.snapshot.children;

    for (var element in dataSnapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = element.value as Map;

      chats.add(MessageModel.fromJson(values));
      print(values);
    }
    return chats;
  }
}
```

Then I call it on my chatscreen.dart

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setupChats();
  }

  _setupChats() async {
    List<MessageModel> chats = await DatabaseService.getChats();
    setState(() {
      _chats = chats;
    });
  }
```

This is my messagemodel.dart

```
class MessageModel {
  String? message;
  String? sendto;
  String? sendby;
  String? status;
  String? type;
  String? time;

  MessageModel(
    this.message,
    this.sendto,
    this.sendby,
    this.status,
    this.type,
    this.time,
  );

  MessageModel.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json)
      : message = json['message'],
        sendto = json['sendto'],
        sendby = json['sendby'],
        status = json['status'],
        type = json['type'],
        time = json['time'];

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "message": message,
      "sendto": sendto,
      "sendby": sendby,
      "status": status,
      "type": type,
      "time": time,
    };
  }

}
```

Replying John's comment. Here is My StreamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder(
                      stream: messages.onChildAdded,
                      builder: (context, snap) {
                        if (snap.hasData &&
                            !snap.hasError &&
                            snap.data!.snapshot.value != null) {
                          Map data = snap.data!.snapshot.value as Map;
                          List item = [];
                          data.forEach(
                         (key, value) => item.add({"key": key, ...data}));
                          // print(data);
                          return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: item.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return ListTile(
                                  title: Text(item[index]['message']),
                                );
                              });
                        } else
                          return Center(
                         child: Text('no data'),
                      );
                  }),
```

Then my messages.onChildAdded is `var messages = database.child('chats');`

It is returning 6 times of `"Hello!"` because I have 6 childs in my `"chats"` collection which is `message,sendto,sendby,status,type, and time.` How do I return the all messages that I sent?

Comment: you have to make sure you are streaming the messages collection to get realtime updates. you can use the built-in stream builder or use third-party stream api like riverpod.

Comment: Hi @john , I updated my question. Can you check it?

Comment: that doesnt work either because your `getChat` method is a Future not stream. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHIcJDQbBFs&ab_channel=JohannesMilke) out to learn how to use Stream builder. And [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=te3mSYeZgqw&ab_channel=STARTECH).

Comment: For my StreamBuilder, I am not using my DatabaseService.dart. That was for my listview.builder code.